# You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted

Tags: android-studio, google-play, domain-name

I have found a lot of threads about this issue here already, but none of them are working for me.

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2, and I still have the com.example domain name.  Changing it in the manifest or any other file is causing a score of errors appearing, and my build.gradle only shows this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can somebody please offer me some advice as I have spent a lot of time on this app already?  Thanks in advance:-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

what you have shown in your question is the top-level `build.gradle`.

open the app level `build.gradle` (inside the `app` folder) and change the package name against `applciationId`

you dont need to change the package name everywhere in your code. Just changing it here will generate your `apk` with the provided package name irrespective of how your packages in the `src` folders are named.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you so much!